# Storing multiple logic databases in one physical database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'd like to design a cloud business solution with 4 default tables, a user may add a custom field(Column?) or a add a custom object(Table?).

My first thought was to create a new database for each account but there's a limit to database number on a sql server instance,

2nd solution : for each account create a new schema by duplicating the 4 default tables for each schema.

3rd solution : create 4 unique tables with a discriminant column (ACCOUNT_ID), if a user wants a new field add a join table dedictated to that ACCOUNT_ID, if he wants a new object then create a new table.

What are your thoughts? Does any body know how existing cloud solutions store data? (for instance salesforce)

BTW, I don't want to create a VM for each account.

Comment: Well, you might ask how SQLFiddle works . . . and it is explained here (http://sqlfiddle.com/about.html#howWorks).

Comment: There's an interesting article about possible multi-tenant architectures here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx  Would be useful reading if you're embarking on this kind of project.

Comment: I like the schema solution because it would be easy to grant locked down permission to specific users to specific schema and would be easy to dynamically script out query logic based upon some business entity variable.

Comment: For your second solution - in DB2 schemas, objects in different schemas can be joined together, and I believe SQL Server is the same way (you wouldn't need to copy the 4 tables each time).  Is there some sort of bounded problem set (eg, is it always the 'same' optional column)?  What are you expecting to store?  Problems often tend to be more definable than initially believed.  If not... this may be a time where an [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) is appropriate, although I dislike them in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions, that helped me a lot especially the microsoft article suggested by John.

Since few architectural points are shared between accounts (the 4 default tables are just a suggestion for the user, I expect a full customization), I've opted for the schema per account design with no EAV pattern.